# Adding table of contents as a "chapter"

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

I´m beginning my project with the chapter "thesis statement" in front of the table of contents and the list of abbreviations (also a chapter). I know that you can add custom entries to the toc via `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\Roman{chapter}.~~~Table of Contents}`. So my table of contents looks like this:

```
I thesis statement
II Table of Contents
III List of Abbreviations
1 Introduction
...
```

What bothers me though is that the table of contents itself is not numbered. Is there a way to add the toc as a chapter?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It can be done with package  `tocbibind `. But why have the toc self-mentioning? When you're reading the table of contents, do you fear not to find it?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! Maybe I need to clarify my question: I was not looking for a way to add the toc as an entry in it. Instead I wanted to nummerate the toc itself like a chapter. I don´t fear not to find the toc when reading in it, but I think it would not look complete without it.

Comment: In all the books I have read I have never seen a numbered ToC.

Comment: If I saw the TOC listed in the TOC I would think the author has a sense of humor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: For KOMA-Script based documents you can nummerate the toc like a chapter with `\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}` before `\begin{document}`.